# Find rowIndex of currentCell

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the rowIndex of the [getCurrentCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection#getcurrentcell) to use it in logic such as creating dynamic ranges.

I've used the [attached spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit#gid=0) with a sheet named "Scratch Pad" to test the functionality. However, all that appears in the run log is that the rowIndex is 1, wherever the currentCell is in the spreadsheet.

I'm new to Google Apps Script(ing) and I may be missing something re class inheritance or something along those lines. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
/**
* Attempting to return the rowIndex of the currentCell!
* @customfunction
*/
function custom_function() 
{

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scratch Pad");
    var selection = sheet.getSelection();
    // Returns the current highlighted cell in the one of the active ranges.
    var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell(); //sheet.getRange(sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() + 1,1); 
    var currentCellRowIndex = sheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();  //currentCell.getRowIndex();
    Logger.log(("The values are " + currentCellRowIndex));

}
```

Comment: So instead of returning the value on that cell, you want to return the number of cell? Like, the row selected is  `4`.  Or is it something different? When you select a different cell in the Sheet, do you still get `1` no matter in which row you're selecting?

Comment: [Edit] to explain how this function is called.

Comment: Yes that's the idea. I can use the row number in other functions to refer to a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the answer a little, I tested this sample code with some of the options you were testing in your code, and they all work properly.

```
function custom_function3() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scratch Pad");
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
  var currentCellRowIndex = currentCell.getRowIndex();
  var currentCellRow = currentCell.getRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(currentCellRow + 1, 1);
  var currentCellRowValue = currentCell.getValue();
  var cellRowIndexForRange = range.getRowIndex()

  Logger.log('currentCellRowIndex: ' + currentCellRowIndex +
    '\ncurrentCellRow: ' + currentCellRow +
    '\nrange: ' + range + 
    '\ncurrentCellRowValue: ' + currentCellRowValue +
    '\ncellRowIndexForRange: ' + cellRowIndexForRange)
}
```

When you run it, you get the following results:

[image: data]

[image: test]

Or second test.

[image: second test]

You can read more information about [getRow and getRowIndex](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow) on the following documentation.

Comment: I'm still only getting currentCellRowIndex: 1, currentCellRow: 1, range: Range, currentCellRowValue: , cellRowIndexForRange: 2

Comment: @Drew254 That's odd, your user selected another cell? Like manually selected any cell in the sheet, and making sure the border of the cell turns blue? If you did, I will say it might be a bug. Have you tried on a new Google Sheet?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I'm on the same page that this is some type of bug. Everything that you've provided puts me on the path for resolving the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help, if you want to report I, I think you could do it using the issue tracker of Google [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#developer_product_feedback)

Answer (score 1):

```
SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().getRow();
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but I'm still only getting: Info 1.0 when this snippet of code is run.